# How do you convert JSON data to array without keys?

Tags: php, json, php-7

I have a set of JSON rules that I am attempting to convert to a PHP array.

This is the set of rules:

```
{
"rules" : {
    "full_name" : "required",
    "email" : {
        "required" : true,
        "email" : true
    },
    "phone" : {
        "required" : true,
        "maxlength" : 10
    },
    "comments" : {
        "minlength" : 10
    }
}
}
```

This is the final output I am working towards:

```
        $rules = [
        'full_name' =>  'required',
        'email'     =>  [ 'required', 'email'],
        'phone'     =>  [ 'max_length' => 10 ],
        'message'   =>  [ 'min_length' => 10 ]
    ];
```

I've created this translation method that reads the json data after json_decode:

```
 private function convertRules($rules)
{
    $convertedRules = [];

    foreach( $rules as $key => $value ) {

        if( is_array($value)) {

            $value = $this->convertRules($value);
        }

        switch( $key ) {

            case '1':

                $value = $key;

                break;

            case 'minlength':

                $key = 'min_length';

                break;

            case 'maxlength':

                $key = 'max_length';

                break;
        }

        switch( $value ) {

            case '1':

                $value = $key;

                break;
        }

        $convertedRules[$key] = $value;
    }


    return $convertedRules;
}
```

But it creates an array with keys that duplicate the values.

```
    Array
(
    [full_name] => required
    [email] => Array
        (
            [required] => required
            [email] => email
        )

    [phone] => Array
        (
            [required] => required
            [max_length] => 10
        )

    [comments] => Array
        (
            [min_length] => 10
        )

)
```

How can I get an array without keys similar to the PHP rules array above?

Any PHP7 optimizations are also appreciated!

Comment: Was the final output for the `phone` key supposed to be `'phone'     =>  [ 'required', 'max_length' => 10 ]`?

Comment: Good catch, yes you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your `convert_rules` function to produce the desired result like so:

```
function convert_rules($rules) {
    $result = [];

    foreach ($rules as $name => $ruleSet) {
        if (!is_array($ruleSet)) {
            $result[$name] = $ruleSet;
        } else {
            $result[$name] = [];

            foreach ($ruleSet as $rule => $value) {
                switch ($rule) {
                    case 'maxlength':
                        $result[$name]['max_length'] = $value;
                        break;

                    case 'minlength':
                        $result[$name]['min_length'] = $value;
                        break;

                    default:
                        $result[$name][] = $rule;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

As you can see, the default behaviour is to insert the rules without keys. For anything else, it's enough to create a separate `case`.

Comment: Wow, I totally over thought that.Thank you.